# How can you automatically update database values using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The shop on my website adjusts the quantities of items when an item is added or removed from the shopping basket. However if someone were to come to the site and add 10 of one item to the shopping basket and left without removing those 10 items they would never be returned to the database.

How do I make it so the item quantities are replenished if someone leaves the site before removing them from the basket? A cron perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the items need to be 'reserved' as soon as the user puts them into his basket?

### Yes

When the user reserves an item, store the time it was reserved at in a table. When calculating the number of items available for a product, subtract the number of currently reserved items.

When/if the user pays for the item, remove the item from the reserved table and mark it as bought.

Then use a cron to remove all items still in the reserved table after time `x`.

The downside of this is that the users basket will be emptied after time `x`, so you must inform the user how much time they have left to pay for their items.

This is more suited for items in high demand, that are likely to go out of stock before they are paid for. For example, event tickets.

### No

Don't mark items as reserved when the user puts them in their basket, and check the stock again when the user pays for it. If the product has gone out of stock since they put the items in their basket, display an error.

This is easier and more suited to low-demand products.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script which would clean the stale backets (those last accessed more than 2 hours ago, for instance) and call it in a cron.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cron job that would automatically remove elements from clients cart every X hours after the item was put in the cart but this might remove items from carts that are still being used by active users so this might be looked down upon.

A way to do what you want would also to use JavaScript to catch the user closing the website/going afk for X hours. Once either of the elements have been triggered you can make an AJAX call to remove the items from the cart and update the website accordingly. This seems like the most straightforward solution to your question "when they leave the site" but won't really solve the issue if the cookie gets destroyed by the client itself.

Either way, you need to consider a way to ensure that the data on the client side, the session and the database are synced to ensure that no items are "orphan" and no purchase is done on items that do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is very difficult to identify when a user has left a site and is not going to return. There are many methods but not all are fool proof. The best one as per me I am detailing below:

The visitor can be a registered user or a new user who has not signed up yet. Your code should save the cart contents in a database table along with the time it was added. The records need to be identified with a user - registered or unregistered. When registered then it is easy as you simply save the registered user's ID in the cart table. If it is a not-registered user then you need to use cookies and save a ID on both the cart table and on the cookie.

If the user leaves and returns in a specific period of time e.g. 1 hr then the user can then see the cart contents intact.

In the meantime, you need to code a script that will find cart contents which are older than 1 hr and delete them and return the stock to your inventory. You can setup a cron that will run this script every few mins e.g. 15 mins etc.

If a user returns after this process has run then the cart will not contain the added items and the user will be required to add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the quantity from your stock until they've fully completed the purchase.

Answer (score -1):

Use cookies for this. I use it's method in my clients shops.
Example: http://magazinsvarki.ru/

Comment: Sorry guys, but this is not the correct logic of the shop. Given this, if the site stayed 10,000 customers and each ordered a 3.2 position of the goods, the store would be empty, since all items are reserved by some clients, we do not even know. All new customers whether they call or infantrymen entered the site would know that the item is not available. Idea use cookies good, when a customer decides to order, then u can reserve products.

Comment: And this one, if use cookie it is possible to reduce the load on the server.